# grep with a string variable and a regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I am trying to match a regular expression whose string part is contained in a variable as in :

```
matches=`grep "^"$*"[ ][0-9]\{1,\}" --count phonelist.txt`
```

where the regex would mean "any line in  phonelist.txt which starts with the command line arguments followed by a space and a number with arbitrary many digits". Have tried many things but can't seem to get it.
Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try:

```
IFS=" "
matches=$(grep "^$* [0-9]\+" --count phonelist.txt)
```

bash's man page says: `$*` "expands to a single word with the value of each parameter separated by the first character of the `IFS` special variable" whereas with `$@` "each parameter expands to a separate word.  That is, "`$@`" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" ...".
In your regular expression you will need all the arguments joined into one single word.

Comment: Thanks - will check it home - unfortunately my remote shell says IFS: undefined variable but will check this - edit : was tsch.

Comment: The `IFS=" "` is necessary in `bash` (which I expected to be used by you) to control the expansion of `$*`. It means that all elements of `$*` are joined into one string, separated by " ". `IFS` means "Internal Field Separator".

Comment: I thought the default IFS to be ' ', \t, \n - and the first one is to be used. So the default is ' ' - IFS=" " is needed if someone/you have changed the default - correct ?

Comment: Yes, that's true. You simply have to ensure that the first element of `IFS` is a space - which is true by default. If you didn't change the variable, you don't need to set it to " ".

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
matches=$(grep "^$* [0-9]\+" --count phonelist.txt)
```

Comment: gives `grep: iygfiyhgv [0-9]\+: No such file or directory` when called with parameters : a iygfiyhgv.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: This is one of those instances where `$*` is necessary instead of `$@`. Sorry for the confusion. Please try the revised version.

Comment: ``grep --count "^$* [0-9]\+" phonelist.txt`` I used - seems to work (will test more).

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: Yes, it's not picky about the order of the arguments in this case. I would ordinarily use them in the order you show in your comment, but in my answer I followed the order you had in your question.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this - I also meant I used the \` \` notation instead of the `$()` - which seems ok (it just now occurred to me to escape the \` to see it in the comments).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to treat each command line argument as a separate pattern (i.e. you want a “match” if a line starts with *any* of command line arguments), then you might construct your whole extended regular expression like this:

```
^(arg1|arg2|arg3|...) [0-9]+
```

You can use set IFS to `|` and use `$*` to automatically expand your positional parameters into that form like this:

```
(IFS=\|; echo "^($*) [0-9]+")
```

The parentheses form a subshell so that the changed IFS is limited to the commands in the parentheses (you may not want that setting to affect later parts of the script.

You will need to be careful when using command line arguments that contain extended regular expression metacharacters. For example, if you wanted to search for the literal string `foo(bar)`, you would need to pass something like `foo\(bar\)` as the argument (an ERE that matches the literal string), which you might write as `'foo\(bar\)'` on an actual command line.

Finally, put it back into your original command and tell `grep` to expect an extended regular expression (`-E`):

```
matches=$(IFS=\|; grep -E "^($*) [0-9]+" --count phonelist.txt)
```

The command substitution `$()` is effectively its own subshell, so the modified IFS value will not “escape” into later parts of the script.

Comment: will check it once I get home and post back - I do need all the parameters (they will form the name in the phone list which can be arbitrary long/short like _john_ or _wolfgang amadeus mozart_)

Comment: If you plan on passing individual name components to as separate parameters, then you will want the method that the other answers show (just plain `$*` instead of `IFS=\|` and `($*)`). My answer would be for if you wanted to write `script 'wolfgang amadeus mozart' 'johann sebastian bach'` (multi-word names are quoted so they go into single arguments and multiple arguments supply alternate strings (patterns, really) to match).